# wpcli: Error on post_content or post_title if accents

Tags: wp-cli

When I try to create a new post with accents width wp-cli (in windows 10 command, I got latest wp-cli)

```
wp post create  --post_title="Héllo" --post_type=page --post_content="Héllo world"
```

I got error:

> "Impossible to insert this post in database"

It works fine when I replace the "é" by "e"

```
wp post create  --post_title="Hello" --post_type=page --post_content="Hello world"
```

Any idea ?

Comment: i didn't use WPLI but the issue relates to sanitization, your data should be sanitized, and indeed there is a way to sanitize insertions, search for it or I hope anyone can post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Cannot create a post with Latin characters in the title on Windows](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/common-issues/#cannot-create-a-post-with-latin-characters-in-the-title-on-windows).

> Using UTF-8 in PHP arguments doesn’t work on Windows for PHP <= 7.0,
>   however it will work for PHP >= 7.1, as it was fixed as part of
>   [Support for long and UTF-8 path](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.windows-support.php). A workaround for PHP <= 7.0 is
>   to use the `--prompt` option:
>
> ```
> echo "Perícias Contábeis" | wp post create --post_type=page --post_status=publish --prompt=post_title
> ```

It looks a bit as if this bug only affects the title. Have you tried that? And the post content doesn't matter? Then the following should work:

```
echo "Héllo" | wp post create --post_type=page --post_content="Héllo world" --prompt=post_title
```

Comment: It affects title and also content

Comment: @yarek – Dayum! Then you'll need to do quite some Bash voodoo to get this running in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/Bash Terminal, you can convert the post title from Latin1 to UTF8 so it can be passed to PHP (it seems to be a PHP problem, not WP-Cli issue)

```
myposttitle=$(echo "My làtin commànd" | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8)

wp-cli post create --post_title="$myposttitle"
```

iconv is a Bash command that can convert the encoding of an incoming text and output it to another encoding.

Comment: I thought Linux terminals were UTF-8 by default?